# Why is $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$ preferred than $\mathbb{E}X < \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the context of measure theoretic probability theory, $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}X < \infty$ are equivalent for any random variable $X$. However, I found that most literatures use the former expression instead of the simpler (in terms of the number of symbols and visual easiness) later expression in the statements of theorems. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Your first statement that they are equivalent is false.  $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$ implies $\mathbb{E}X < \infty$ but not the other way around.

Comment: @BrianMoehring How so? $X$ is integrable iff $|X|$ is. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @tangentbundle $\mathbb{E} |X|^p < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E} X^p < \infty$ are equivalent. Are you saying about "value" of $L^p$ norm rather than the membership for $L^p$?

Comment: @tangentbundle I would have liked OP to figure it out for themselves, but you may yet have $\mathbb{E}X = -\infty$.  The correct equivalence is $$\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty \iff (\mathbb{E}X \text{ exists and } |\mathbb{E}X|<\infty),$$ which for me shows that $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$ is much more compact than its equivalent statement involving $\mathbb{E}X$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks! Would you make your comment an answer? It was a silly question but I think there may be students having similar confusion. It would be better to make the correct answer explicit.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Right, thank you. I'll take down my previous comment since it is claiming something that is not quite correct.

Answer (score 1):

$E |X| $ is always well defined, though sometimes it is infinite. It is best to avoid stating a condition in terms of a possibly undefined quantity.

Also, in some cases (e.g. if $X$ and $-X$ have the same law), there are other integration theories where $E(X)$ can be defined despite $E|X|$ being infinite (e.g., Cauchy principal value, or Riemann improper integrals). There is no ambiguity in asking whether $E|X|$ is finite or not.